# With VS-Code, I can't utilise the emmet option for Styled-component in React

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, styled-components

Using VS-code, I'm attempting to use emmet for styled-components in react. I've tried every tip on the internet, but I still can't get it.

- I have tried to install extensions like **vscode-styled-components**
- i have added  `"emmet.includeLanguages": { "jsx": "javascriptreact, css", "javascript": "javascriptreact, css" }, in my settings.json`
- for reference if we type`df` it will be added as `display:flex`
  but still im not getting it help me with solving this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **vscode-styled-components** extension in VSCode.
Link [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=styled-components.vscode-styled-components).

[image]It's an awesome Extension of VSCode.

Comment: The first bullet says that they've tried that.